# Zeros of polynomial functions: Find the dimensions of the box with width w, Length 2w and height w+2

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm reading through a textbook chapter section on zeros of polynomial functions. The exercise I am on:

Find the dimensions of the box described (inches):
The length is twice the width and the height is the width + 2. The volume is 192.

The solution is provided as $8*4*6$ inches. I am unable to arrive at this. My working:

$l=2w$, $w=w$, $h=w+2$
$$v=lwh$$
$$192=2ww(w+2)$$
$$192=2w^3+2w^2$$
$$0=2w^3+2w^2-192$$
$$0=w^3+w^2-96$$

I tried two approached here. First I used the rational zero theorem to come up with candidate zeros. Since my leading coefficient is 1 after my last step of dividing everything by 2, my potential zeros are factors of -96: $\pm 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 24, 32, 48, 96$

Using synthetic division I went through several of these looking for a value that has a remainder of 0 when dividing $w^3+w^2-96$. But I could not find any.

Then I trued substitution:
let u = $w^2$:

I now have a quadratic:
$$0=u^2+u-96$$

I then tried to apply some learning after watching [a simpler quadratic formula](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHXO86wKeDY) by 3b1b on youtube. Using this approach I arrived at roots of $\frac{-1}{2}\pm\sqrt{96+\frac{1}{4}}$.

But given the content in my current chapter in the book, I don't think I'm supposed to be using substitution anyway and that the expectation is that I can do this using the rational zero theorem and the factors of -96.

How can I arrive at $8*4*6$ inches? Preferably via rational zero theorem if it's possible, else what's a logical approach here?

Comment: If $w^2=u\implies u^{\frac{3}{2}}=w^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your final equation is wrong. It should be $$w^3 + 2w^2 - 96 = 0$$
and second of all quadratic formulas and
quadratic equations would not work here since the equation is a cubic polynomial.   Factorizing the equation we have $$w^3 + 2w^2 - 96 = 0$$ $$(w - 4)(w^2 + 6w + 24) = 0$$    Then from $w = 4$ and you have $l = 8$, $w = 4$, $h = 6$.

Comment: I tried synthetically dividing $w^3-2w^2-96$ with 4 per your factor but this leaves me with a remainder, $x^2+6x-72$, expected/was looking for a remainder of 0. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: The second term is not $-2w^3$ but $+2w^3$. Taking w=4, we have $$4^3 + 
2×4^2 - 96$$. Solving we have 0. Therefore, w=4 is a root.

Answer (score 3):

You have a simple mistake when distributing. The rational root theorem will work once you arrive at $$192 = 2w^3 + 4w^2$$